# Google play developer console crashes and ANRs

Tags: android, android-anr-dialog, developer-console

I can see some application crashes reported in **Crashes & ANRs** section in my Google Play developer console. I can view the stack trace of the crashes there.

What I want to know is, does android always collect data about crashes or does the user need to manually report the crash, for me to be able to view the crash report in developer console? I have seen several apps crash on my device, but I cannot remember that I was asked for a confirmation to report the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> does the user need to manually report the crash, for me to be able to
>   view the crash report in developer console?

It appears in the developer console only if the user reports it. The user can also choose to add a message with the report.

The report prompt looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

May be this answer is not relevant to your question, but it helps you.

Try to go for tools like crashlytics, crittercism ...

Crashlytics is free of cost. You can handle non-fatals too (Exception occurred in try catch, but u need to log those to dashboard.)

No need to depend upon the google console crash report.